# Отправка формы методом POST

Tags: post, php, get

Здравствуйте.

Есть 1 страничка, она кидает через (submit) post на php переменную,

```
<form action="order.php" method="post" target="">
```

Во втором php, я как бы принимаю это дело в input. И во втором тоже нажимаю, (submit) post, потом проверяю `if(@$_POST["submit"])` и рисую др.содержание. Но вот, если ставить GET в первом, то всё нормально, а если ставить POST в первом файле, то во втором сразу срабатывает `if(@$_POST["submit"])` и рисуется уже результат работы второго php.

Я понял, что приходит имя submita из первого файла, но я менял имя, и всё равно получается то же самое. Первый submit заставляет сразу прыгать на конечный результат.
Как этого избежать?

Comment: $_POST- супер глобальный массив, всё правильно, что срабатывает обработчик второй страницы. Что если проверять вместо submit name  button name?

Comment: И дайте исходники, попробую покавыряться

Comment: Вот да, именно! Я через $_POST["submit"] вижу, что приходит value от второго.
Сейчас попробую с button name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если честно, то не стал вникать в ваш вопрос, вот пример вам нужный :

файл form.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="./here.php?step=2" method="post">
<input type="text" name="textfield" /><br />
<input type="button" value="Отправить" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

файл here.php :

```
<?php

if ($_GET['step'] == '2') {
    echo 'Было отправлено : '.$_POST['textfield'];
}

?>
```

Запросы :

Один от другого отличаются по скорости не более чем на 1/10 милисекунды, а вот как они работают т.е. как происходит отправка - разница есть. GET - запрос можно составить самому, например : ?s1=123&name=andrej&m=10 и т.д., в итоге в сценарии, которым мы обрабатываем можно будет получить эти данные с помощью $_GET['s1'], $_GET['name'] и т.д. А вот POST - запрос нужно формировать с помощью формы и заголовков, если перезагрузить страницу, на которую вас отправила форма POST - запросом, то обозреватель вас предупредит о повторной отправке данных формы, а при GET - запросе такого предупреждения не будет. В GET - запросе все данные передаются в URL, а в POST - запросе - в заголовках.

Comment: А кстати по функциональности, какой запрос шустрее? Get или POST?  
  
  
P.S. прочитал это http://myrusakov.ru/raznica-post-get.html  
 И думаю, для моего примера, надо использовать GET  
 Так как передаю лишь "текст1 текст2"

Comment: Если запрашивается информация с сервера (к примеру форма для поиска) - значит GET, если данные изменяются, записываются (к примеру авторизация, регистрация, загрузка файлов и т.д.) тогда POST. Еще метод POST следует использовать для передачи большого объема данных...

Answer (score 0):

> если ставить GET в первом, то всё
> нормально, а если ставить POST в
> первом файле, то во втором сражу
> срабатывает if(@$_POST["submit"])

Я лично ничего не понял. Если в первом файле поставить метот GET, то во втором файле условие не сработает "так как POST не отправлялся".

Comment: на сколько я понял, то POST запрос есть и на второй странице.

Comment: abibock_un - да, именно.
Наверное отсановлюсь на GET.
просто вдруг в другой раз понадобиться POST вот и решил разобраться.